# Dynamic components at specified index not placed properly

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-directive

I am trying to show a simple list of items in Angular with a clickable div on the side; on user selection, the component should dynamically create a new component below the clicked one.

For this purpose, i am using `ComponentFactoryResolver` with no relevant problems; however, using `ViewContainerRef` as parent, i can't find how to place the created components at a specified index, even if i specify it as a parameter in the `createComponent()` method.

**app.component.html**

```
<h3>Click on the arrow to create a component below the item clicked.</h3>

<div #myContainer>
  <div *ngFor="let thing of things; let index = index">
    <div class="inline click" (click)="thingSelected(thing, index)"> > </div>
    <div class="inline">{{thing.id}}</div>
    <div class="inline">{{thing.name}}</div>
    <div class="inline">{{thing.value}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent  {  
  @ViewChild('myContainer', { read: ViewContainerRef }) container: ViewContainerRef;

  things = [];
  constructor(private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver){
    for(let i=0; i < 10; i++)
      this.things.push({id: i, name: "thing" + i, value: 5 * i});    
  }

  thingSelected(thing: any, index: number){
    let component = this.container.createComponent(this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(DetailComponent), index);
    component.instance.id = thing.id;    
  }
}
```

I also created a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gd796h?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html) sample to demostrate the issue: what i am missing or doing wrong?

To clarify:

1. I would like to reproduce something similar to ["RowExpand" functionality](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/table/rowexpansion) in TurboTable of PrimeNg library.
   The user clicks a row, and a dynamic component is created **at the position clicked**.
2. I don't know the type of component at runtime: that's why i want a dynamic component creation (**so, specifying it in the html template it's not what i need**)

Comment: You example works as long as your "index collection" is continous - so in order to have component placed @ index 5 you need to have 5 components already. If you add evertything from 0 to 9 you will notice that any future additions will work like you desired. \

Comment: I need to insert the dynamically created components "inside" the NgFor list, not at the end of it. To be more clear, i need to insert a component at index N of the NgFor.

Comment: So you wanted actually to insert components inbetween divs ?

Comment: Exactly: i would like to reproduce something like the "RowExpand" of PrimeNg (see link in my question)

Answer (score 4):

Ok, here is working example with `@ViewChildren`

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gxmj4s?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

```
  @ViewChildren('details', { read: ViewContainerRef }) containers: QueryList<ViewContainerRef>;

  thingSelected(thing: any, index: number) {
    const containersArray = this.containers.toArray();
    let component = containersArray[index].createComponent(this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(DetailComponent));
    component.instance.id = thing.id;
  }
```

And

```
<div #myContainer>
  <div *ngFor="let thing of things; let index = index">
    <div class="inline click" (click)="thingSelected(thing, index)"> > </div>
    <div class="inline">{{thing.id}}</div>
    <div class="inline">{{thing.name}}</div>
    <div class="inline">{{thing.value}}</div>
    <div #details></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Results in

[image]

Comment: this solves my issue, but i wonder if i can avoid compleately to use the @vieChildren and related div: i would like to insert the element at a certain index in the container.
In jquery, i would have solved this issue like that: 
$('div:eq('+index'+)').after('myComponent');

Comment: then use jQuery

Comment: As you certainly knows, Angular discourages using jquery because (almost) all of its features can be reproduced with the use of Angular APIs on DOM Manipulation.
In fact, ViewContainerRef has a method called insert(), wich can be used to insert some components at a certain index.
I can't just find a proper way to use it

Comment: *(almost) all of its features can be reproduced with the use of Angular APIs on DOM Manipulation.* I just did that and you are still not satisfied. You can achieve the same thing but nobody says it must nor can be done the same way. You need to see the difference there

Comment: The existence of an api called "insert()", though, lend me think that the possibility to insert a component in a ViewContainerRef should exist. thanks anyway for your support

Comment: Idk, maybe there is, or maybe not - never had to use it thus never explored that path. To me using @ViewChildren introduces strong MVC as I am decupling view from logic and I use only data model interact (in this case, set of custom components/placeholders.

Comment: just curious to know..In what ways does using viewChildren has benefit over this logic..https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hf9zis

Comment: @ShadabFaiz did you change something? Looks the same.

Comment: my mistake..i forgot to save them...i have updated the link.

Comment: OP stated somewhere that component type will be variable.